# How to place items in flexbox take equal width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to place the items in the flexbox take the same width.

Within the flexbox I have a searchsvg, input field and div with some text. I want each of them to take equal width themselves based on the width of the flexbox. I don't want to provide the width of each item manually. I tried using `justify-content: space-evenly`. In doing so, the input field takes more width than rest of them.

How can I avoid it? Below is the code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.items_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  .items_container.expanded {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.items_container.expanded .search_input_field {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items_container expanded">
    <div class="search_input_field">
      <div>
        <Svgsearch/>
      </div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="input" />
    </div>
    <div>dropdown to be added</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: First thing I can see is wrong that you are applying flex-grow: 1 to wrapper ... which is property for child elements of flexbox.

Comment: You did it right, but you have to just delete your wrapper. Then if you want the items to resize, use `items_container > div { flex: 1 0 0 }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved `flex-grow: 1` from where you placed it, because it wasn't doing anything. This is a rule that affects flex children. Therefore, I moved it to affect all direct children of the flex parent, `.wrapper`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-grow: 1; <-- moved below */

  & > * {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtbvrpk1/2/)

Answer (score 1):

`.child` elements should `grow` equally and not `shrink`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
} 

.child {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}


/* ignore */
.child {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightcoral;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```